# Exception handling in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

What exception handling can I add in the code below? I tried the output with different inputs but it won't give any error, so I am bit confused on what exception handling I can add to this program.

```
import urllib2
import urllib
import json

url = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&"
query = raw_input("What do you want to search for ? >> ")
query = urllib.urlencode( {'q' : query } )
response = urllib2.urlopen (url + query ).read()
data = json.loads ( response )
results = data [ 'responseData' ] [ 'results' ]

for result in results:
    title = result['title']
    url = result['url']
    print ( title + '; ' + url )
```

Comment: You can add any exception handling you want.

Comment: If you want to raise an exception use the `raise` keyword.

Comment: `urllib2.urlopen` can fail if the URL is invalid, `json.loads` can fail if the JSON is malformed, `results = data [ 'responseData' ] [ 'results' ]` can fail if there is no such field and so on and so on.

Answer (score 3):

You should first surround the `urlopen` call with a `try` block, [since this function can raise `IOError`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlopen). The same [for the JSON response](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html), but with `ValueError`. For simplicity, you can put these two lines in the same `try` block and catch each exception:

```
url = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&"
query = raw_input("What do you want to search for ? >> ")
query = urllib.urlencode({'q' : query })
try:
    response = urllib2.urlopen (url + query).read()
    data = json.loads(response)
except IOError:
    print("Unable to fetch results")
except ValueError:
    print("Invalid response return by the API")
else:
    results = data['responseData']['results']

    for result in results:
        title = result['title']
        url = result['url']
        print("%s; %s" % (title, url))
```

After, the access to `data['responseData']['results']` and `result[...]` can lead to a `KeyError` also if the API is not consistent. You need to evaluate if you want to put exception handling everywhere or not.

Side-note: Note the string formatting at the last `print` line, more Pythonic than string concatenation.